# Update multiple progress bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I want to update multiple status bars based on time between dates but only the last progress bar on the page is getting updated. I'm new to javascript/jquery so I'm probably doing many things wrong. I would be grateful if you could help me with this problem.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    for(var i = 0, limit = ${tasksLength}; i < limit; i++) {
      var bar = $('#task-progress-' + i);

      var start = moment($('#task-submit-' + i).val(), "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm").toDate();
      var end = moment($('#task-deadline-' + i).val(), "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm").toDate();
      var time = end - start;

      var interval = window.setInterval(function () {
        var elapsed = new Date() - start;
        bar.width(((elapsed / time) * 100) + "%");

        if(elapsed >= limit) {
          window.clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }, 250);
    }
  });
</script>
```

progress bars are created in jstl forEach loop:

```
<c:set var="tasksLength" value="${fn:length(tasks)}" />
<c:forEach items="${tasks}" var="task" varStatus="counter">

  <fmt:formatDate type="both" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm" value="${task.submit}" var="strSubmit" />
  <fmt:formatDate type="both" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm" value="${task.deadline}" var="strDeadline" />

  <input type="hidden" id="task-submit-${counter.index}" value="${strSubmit}">
  <input type="hidden" id="task-deadline-${counter.index}" value="${strDeadline}">

  ...

  <div class="progress">
    <div id="task-progress-${counter.index}" class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                        1d:20h:30m
    </div>
  </div>

  ...
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: It would be grateful if you create a shortest path to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RomanC no need of example here.. its a simple problem of scope of a variable.  please check my answer below that explains the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `bar.width` from inside the callback function within `window.setInterval`, but the variable, `bar` is set outside the callback function. Which makes the scope of `bar` within for loop.

What you need to understand is for-loop runs off for all three `bar`s but none of the setinterval callbacks run for another 250ms. Which is why all your setinterval callbacks modify the last value of of `bar` set in the for loop.

Please feel free to ask for more explanation.

To fix this, you need to isolate the scope of `bar` to the setinterval's callback function. I will leave it up to you to try that :)